# How to transform excel data using macros

Tags: excel

I need to transform excel data to be like this using macros

[example-image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9fSLs.png)

using specific number of rows (in my example : 10 rows)

and thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to SO. I understand it can be hard to get started. However, SO is not intended to be a free coding service. Whereas, as it stands, your question amounts treating it like one. See [help – on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for full details on how to post a valid question.

Answer (score 0):

Please share the steps already taken and where you are having problems.
In general, if your data is fixed then copy 1st and paste it where you want it and then copy the next 10 and repeat.